# Angular2 re-renders on every mouse movement

Tags: angular

I have a Angular2 (2.4.0) application which presents a list in a ngFor loop, and I've noticed that every time a move the mouse the list is getting re-rendered. Has any one else noticed similar behavior and/or know why it's like this?

The table that is getting re-rendered:

```
<table class="responsive-table bordered highlight">
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let person of getPersons()">
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tboby>
</table>
```

I've added a console.log statement in getPersons() and it's getting logged on every mouse movement.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: @per_jansson I have same issue. But I check my code and i don't call any method in loop but I have a method in `option` tag for `disabled` attribute. Any guidance?

Answer (score 2):

Using the method, which return array of objects, is very bad solution.
You should iterate the static array or using pipe (it depends on the case).

Try call your function in *constructor* (or *ngOnInit* method), for example:

In your TypeScript file:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-selector',
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {

   someArray: any[];

   ngOnInit() {
      this.someArray = getPersons();
   } 

   getPersons() {
      //some code...
   }
}
```

and in your HTML file (*template.html*):

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of someArray">
...
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't know if this answers the question 'why does angular re-render on every mouse move'

Comment: This doens't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

The response of @Jaroslaw K. is correct, but it misses one explanation. It's a bad solution to use a function to return a template variable because Angular checks for changes in the template variable to render the template. If you use a function instead of a static variable or a pipe, Angular cannot perform the check, so it executes the function each time you move the mouse to ensure the template is up to date.